# What does an empty locale parameter mean?

Tags: c++, locale

I saw code that used a locale but didn't provide a name for it. I saw this several times actually and I'm not sure how it works.

```
auto& f = std::use_facet<std::ctype<wchar_t>>(std::locale());
```

I was wondering what it means to just use an empty locale constructor. I thought all locale names had to be specified.

For some context, here is where I found the code: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/ctype/toupper

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale/locale was only two clicks away

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/locale/locale/

The default constructor constructs a copy of the current global locale, which is the locale set by a previous call to locale::global, or locale::classic if locale::global has not been called.

**What is `locale::classic`?**

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/locale/classic/

Returns the classic locale, which corresponds in semantics to the "C" locale (the default locale).

**What is the "C" locale?**

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clocale/

The "C" locale is the minimal locale. It is a rather neutral locale which has the same settings across all systems and compilers, and therefore the exact results of a program using this locale are predictable. This is the locale used by default on all C programs.

Comment: Do you know if the "C" locale is the default locale for C++ programs as well?

Comment: I'm merely quoting the reference at the links I provided, but, considering they're all reference for C++ standard classes, I can only assume that is correct. If not, these references have unrelated information that's misleading.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Yes, the default locale in C++ is "C".

Answer (score 2):

`std::locale` has a constructor that takes no parameter. It creates a locale that's a snapshot of the current global locale.